# How can I print repeater data in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I print Repeater data?

I am having a Search page which makes search query according to the input given and populate the repeater. Now I want to print this result displayed in the repeater. How can I do that on the onClick button event of a "Print" asp:Button?

Comment: What do you mean by "repeater"? What's a repeater?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide search capability, follow below steps-

1. If you are filling repeater on PageLoad with whole data, remember to prevent your repeater binding always on PageLoad using IsPostBack property.
2. Now on Click event get the filtered data, and bind it with repeater.

Hope this will solve your problem, If need any help please update your question with code.

Thanks.